# An author 'teaches' or 'taught' us in his book

Tags: grammar, tenses, past-tense, present-tense

Some time ago I posted the following sentence on an online forum:

```
Adam Smith, in his "Wealth of Nations", taught us that...
```

Now I am wondering whether I should have used the word '**teaches**' rather than '**taught**'. Although the author has passed away, we are still being taught by him in his book.

I also noticed that quite often reporters and writers use the present tense when describing what appears to be a past event, which somewhat confuses me. Eg.:

"Akane **survives** thriller against Se-young as Japan **become** champions again" -- The Star, https://www.thestar.com.my/sport/badminton/2020/02/17/akane-survives-thriller-against-se-young-as-japan-become-champions-again

"...The views of Aristotle on ethics **represent**, in the main, the prevailing opinions of educated and experienced men of his day...Aristotle **says** that Plato was right in dividing the soul into two parts..." -- History of Western Philosophy, Bertrand Russell

Why has the past tense not been used in such cases?

Additionally, shouldn't it be '**becomes**' in the first case?

Comment: Use either present or past.  But be consistent.  Do not switch back and forth.  Also: "As Japan become ..."  This is a UK custom, using plural for sports clubs, and other collections of people.  "Manchester United are my favorite football club."  In the US we would use singular verbs for this.

Comment: It's called the literary present (cf. narrative present, historic present). It's natural and a good device for reader engagement.  Start at: [literary present (verbs)](https://www.thoughtco.com/literary-present-verbs-term-1691251)